# LVM + add new partition on the OS disk

Tags: linux, filesystems, lvm, disk

on my Linux redhat machine I we have the following details

```
# pvs
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
 /dev/sda2  vg00 lvm2 a--  149.51g 944.00m



# lsblk
  NAME             MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
  fd0                2:0    1     4K  0 disk
  sda                8:0    0   150G  0 disk
  ├─sda1             8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
  └─sda2             8:2    0 149.5G  0 part
  ├─vg00-lv_root 253:0    0    40G  0 lvm  /
  ├─vg00-lv_swap 253:1    0   7.7G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─vg00-lv_var  253:2    0 100.9G  0 lvm  /var
```

I want to add new partition on the OS disk ( sda ) with the same VG

so it will be something like this ( pvs )

```
# pvs
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
 /dev/sda2  vg00 lvm2 a--  149.51g 944.00m
 /dev/sda.. vg00 lvm   ........
```

please advice what the steps that are needed in order to create the new partition on the OS disk ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How can you create a new partition in your hard drive? You have **no more space left.**

However, if you want to create a new **Logical Volume**, then run :

```
lvcreate -L <The size of the LV> -n <The name of the LV> <name of vg>
mkfs.<format type> <LV path>
```

Comment: what about the VG name - vg00  ?

Comment: I edited the answer adding the vgname  My bad, I forgot.

Comment: do you think that need to run the mke2fs to create FS on this dev?

Comment: Yes. I will update the answer.

Comment: another remark I create it but when I run the command pvs then I see only one line not two , is it logical ?

Comment: To see the Logical Volume's use the lvs command instead of pvs.